# Kinect SDK for HTML 5 Javascript with people recognition of 4 people

Tags: javascript, html, kinect

I am facing the problem that i can't find a SDK for kinect that has the ability to recognise the hipcenter of four different people.

I already looked into these:

[KinectJS](http://kinect.childnodes.com/)

[Kinesis.io](http://kinesis.io)
 *(But the js and css completely dissapeared and they still use 1.1 of kinect, wich is pretty low)*

[Zigfu](http://zigfu.com)

[KinectHTML5](http://kinecthtml5.codeplex.com/)

I must say that we need html5 explicitly for our project. 
And we also need 4 people recognition. So your help and opinion would be appreciated.

So does anyone know a HTML5 - Javascript/Jquery sdk that can recognise 4 or more hipcenters.

I need this alot

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Nope, not a single one

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the official MS Kinect SDK currently can *recognise* 6 users but only *skeletal track* a maximum of 2 users: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973074.aspx

This means that any HTML5/JS library that builds upon the offical SDK will probably share the same limitation. If a JS library uses OpenNI, or some other SDK, then perhaps this limitation could be overcome, but a quick search seems to show it supports a maximum of 2 as well.

I have checked this on an XBox Kinect and Windows Kinect.

Apparently, the XBox One Kinect will be able to skeletal track 4 users.